# Make eclipse Syntax Coloring exact as visual studio Syntax Coloring

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010

Don't ask me why but I want to make eclipse Syntax Coloring exact as visual studio 2010 standard C# Syntax Coloring. I know where to change it in eclipse but I can't get the color codes right. Where can I find the visual studio standard C# Syntax Coloring color code to apply to eclipse?

Do you know any template that may already do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick Web search turns up the [Visual Studio styles on eclisecolorthemes.org](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?list=all&q=visual%20studio).

There are [instructions on the site](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=how-to-use) on how to apply the theme.

Comment: It says they'll be back online shortly. Maybe check back in a day or so...

Comment: Who knows since when they went offline? Do you happen to have a mirror for it? I'm dying to have that color scheme! :)

Comment: Fortunately the site is online now.